# ios8 playground editor not visible

Tags: ios, ios8, swift-playground

I am not able to see editor screen for `.playground` file in Xcode 6.0. Here it only shows **ENTITY MAPPINGS** screen:

How to switch to editor, Tried lot but not able to find in menu.

[image: Playgorund]

Other thing is that even if i trying close this file it shows message like this:

[image]

Did anyone sort out this?

Comment: Not able to open any other `.playground` files too. While this file open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you accidentally changed the type to "Core Data Mapping Model" in "File Inspector".

Try this:

1. Open "File Inspector" by `View`>`Utilities`>`Show File Inspector` (<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)
2. Select `Default - Swift Playground` from `Type` pulldown
3. "Force Quit" Xcode with <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>.

[image: screenshot]